# Vim's normal command doesn't work correctly in command mode

Tags: vim, vi

Input:

```
==abc==

===abc===

====abc====
```

Vim's command mode → `:g/=$/normal b i InsertedtexT`

(aliases: ["norm" and "norm!"](http://web.archive.org/web/20150226023548/http://briancarper.net/blog/165/vim-g-norm)) → Output:

```
==abc==

 InsertedtexT===abc===

 InsertedtexT====abc====
```

Normal mode → `$ b i InsertedtexT` → Output (this is what it should do):

```
==abcInsertedtexT==

===abcInsertedtexT===

====abcInsertedtexT====
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`:g` will not position the cursor at the match, but at the start of the line. And space will move a cursor right (which I assume you did not type when testing in normal mode.) So this happens: `:g` finds a line that ends with equals; `b` takes you to the previous line (except for in the first line, where the execution of `:norm` is aborted as you can't go backwards), so now the cursor is in between lines; space moves you forward, to the beginning of the next line; `i` enters insert mode; and `InsertedtexT` gets inserted part-and-parcel, together with the leading space.

What you wanted to do is exactly what you have done in normal mode:

```
:g/=$/norm! $biInsertedtexT
```

(note no spaces, and note that you need to explicitly go to the end of the line; and `:norm!` just in case, if your environment has any weird mapping going on.)

tl;dr: Vim's normal command does work correctly in command mode.